Error when performing dft to calculate bandgap
import os
import csv
from pymatgen.core.structure import Structure
from pymatgen.io.vasp.sets import MPRelaxSet
from pymatgen.io.vasp.outputs import Vasprun
from custodian.vasp.jobs import VaspJob
from custodian.custodian import Custodian
from custodian.vasp.handlers import VaspErrorHandler, UnconvergedErrorHandler

def run_vasp(structure, directory):
    print(f"Attempting to create directory: {directory}")
    if os.path.exists(directory):
        print(f"Directory {directory} already exists. Removing it.")
        os.system(f"rm -r {directory}")
    os.makedirs(directory)
    print(f"Directory {directory} created.")

    print("Creating MPRelaxSet...")
    relax_set = MPRelaxSet(structure,
                           user_incar_settings={'EDIFF': 0.0001, 'EDIFFG': -0.05, 'LREAL': 'Auto',
                                                'NSW': 200, 'ALGO': 'Normal', 'PREC': 'Normal',
                                                'ISMEAR': -5, 'ISIF': 3, 'LORBIT': '.FALSE.',
                                                'LCHARG': '.FALSE.', 'LWAVE': '.FALSE.',
                                                'LDAU': '.FALSE.', 'ISPIN': 1, 'ISYM': 0},
                           user_kpoints_settings={'reciprocal_density': 32},
                           force_gamma=True)

    print(f"Writing input files to {directory}")
    relax_set.write_input(directory)

    # Check if INCAR file was created
    incar_path = os.path.join(directory, "INCAR")
    if os.path.exists(incar_path):
        print(f"INCAR file created successfully at {incar_path}")
        with open(incar_path, 'r') as incar_file:
            print("INCAR contents:")
            print(incar_file.read())
    else:
        print(f"ERROR: INCAR file was not created at {incar_path}")
        print("Directory contents:")
        print(os.listdir(directory))

    vasp_cmd = ["mpirun", "-np", "1", "vasp_gpu"]
    job = VaspJob(vasp_cmd, final=True, suffix=".relax")
    return job, directory

def main():
    base_dir = "/scratch/harsha.vasamsetti_band"
    input_file = "/scratch/harsha.vasamsetti/harsha.vasamsetti/SLICES/SLICES/MatterGPT/bandgap/2_inverse_novelty/results.csv"
    output_file = os.path.join(base_dir, "results.csv")
    handlers = [VaspErrorHandler(), UnconvergedErrorHandler()]

    if not os.path.exists(input_file):
        print(f"Input file {input_file} not found. Creating an empty file.")
        with open(input_file, 'w') as f:
            f.write("bandgap_target,SLICES,poscar,novelty\n")

    with open(input_file, 'r') as f, open(output_file, 'w') as out_f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        header = next(reader)
        print(f"CSV Header: {header}")
        out_f.write("bandgap_target,SLICES,poscar,novelty,bandgap_DFT\n")

        for i, row in enumerate(reader):
            try:
                print(f"Processing row {i+1}")
                if len(row) != 4:
                    print(f"Warning: Row {i+1} has unexpected number of columns. Skipping.")
                    continue
                bandgap_target, slices, poscar, novelty = row
                poscar = poscar.replace('\\n', '\n')
                structure = Structure.from_str(poscar, fmt="poscar")
                calc_dir = os.path.join(base_dir, f"vasp_run_{i}")
                
                job, calc_dir = run_vasp(structure, directory=calc_dir)
                
                # Update: Pass the correct directory to Custodian
                c = Custodian(handlers, [job], max_errors=3, directory=calc_dir)
                c.run()
                
                vasprun = Vasprun(os.path.join(calc_dir, "vasprun.xml"))
                bandgap = vasprun.get_band_structure().get_band_gap()['energy']
                out_f.write(f"{bandgap_target},{slices},{poscar},{novelty},{bandgap}\n")
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Error processing row {i+1}: {e}")
                import traceback
                traceback.print_exc()
            finally:
                print(f"Cleaning up directory: {calc_dir}")
                os.system(f"rm -rf {calc_dir}")

    print("Finished processing all rows")

I am using the above code to calculate the bandgap in vasp. It takes a crystal and saves it as a csv file where results are calculated.
I am facing a error that I am not understanding as I am newbie in this. pointing out the problem is greatly appreciated
Error:
/home2/harsha.vasamsetti/miniconda3/envs/slices/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymatgen/io/vasp/sets.py:118: BadInputSetWarning: POTCAR data with symbol Rb_sv is not known by pymatgen to correspond with the selected user_potcar_functional='PBE'. This POTCAR is known to correspond with functionals ['PBE_52', 'PBE_54']. Please verify that you are using the right POTCARs!
  warnings.warn(
/home2/harsha.vasamsetti/miniconda3/envs/slices/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymatgen/io/vasp/sets.py:118: BadInputSetWarning: POTCAR data with symbol In_d is not known by pymatgen to correspond with the selected user_potcar_functional='PBE'. This POTCAR is known to correspond with functionals ['PBE_52', 'PBE_54']. Please verify that you are using the right POTCARs!
  warnings.warn(
/home2/harsha.vasamsetti/miniconda3/envs/slices/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymatgen/io/vasp/sets.py:118: BadInputSetWarning: POTCAR data with symbol O is not known by pymatgen to correspond with the selected user_potcar_functional='PBE'. This POTCAR is known to correspond with functionals ['PBE_52', 'PBE_54']. Please verify that you are using the right POTCARs!
  warnings.warn(
BZINTS
ERROR:custodian.custodian:VaspErrorHandler
ERROR:VaspErrorHandler:BZINTS
ERROR:custodian.custodian:VaspErrorHandler
ERROR:VaspErrorHandler:BZINTS
ERROR:custodian.custodian:VaspErrorHandler
ERROR:custodian.custodian:Max errors per job reached: 3.
/home2/harsha.vasamsetti/miniconda3/envs/slices/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymatgen/io/vasp/sets.py:118: BadInputSetWarning: POTCAR data with symbol Li_sv is not known by pymatgen to correspond with the selected user_potcar_functional='PBE'. This POTCAR is known to correspond with functionals ['PBE_52', 'PBE_54']. Please verify that you are using the right POTCARs!
  warnings.warn(
/home2/harsha.vasamsetti/miniconda3/envs/slices/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymatgen/io/vasp/sets.py:118: BadInputSetWarning: POTCAR data with symbol Cr_pv is not known by pymatgen to correspond with the selected user_potcar_functional='PBE'. This POTCAR is known to correspond with functionals ['PBE_52', 'PBE_54']. Please verify that you are using the right POTCARs!
  warnings.warn(
/home2/harsha.vasamsetti/miniconda3/envs/slices/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymatgen/io/vasp/sets.py:118: BadInputSetWarning: POTCAR data with symbol Sb is not known by pymatgen to correspond with the selected user_potcar_functional='PBE'. This POTCAR is known to correspond with functionals ['PBE_52', 'PBE_54']. Please verify that you are using the right POTCARs!
  warnings.warn(
/home2/harsha.vasamsetti/miniconda3/envs/slices/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymatgen/io/vasp/sets.py:118: BadInputSetWarning: POTCAR data with symbol O is not known by pymatgen to correspond with the selected user_potcar_functional='PBE'. This POTCAR is known to correspond with functionals ['PBE_52', 'PBE_54']. Please verify that you are using the right POTCARs!
  warnings.warn(
ERROR:VaspErrorHandler:BRMIX: very serious problems
ERROR:custodian.custodian:VaspErrorHandler
ERROR:VaspErrorHandler:BRMIX: very serious problems
ERROR:VaspErrorHandler:REAL_OPT: internal ERROR
ERROR:custodian.custodian:VaspErrorHandler
ERROR:VaspErrorHandler:BRMIX: very serious problems
ERROR:VaspErrorHandler:LAPACK: Routine ZPOTRF failed
ERROR:custodian.custodian:VaspErrorHandler
ERROR:custodian.custodian:Max errors per job reached: 3.
/home2/harsha.vasamsetti/miniconda3/envs/slices/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymatgen/io/vasp/sets.py:118: BadInputSetWarning: POTCAR data with symbol Sr_sv is not known by pymatgen to correspond with the selected user_potcar_functional='PBE'. This POTCAR is known to correspond with functionals ['PBE_52', 'PBE_54']. Please verify that you are using the right POTCARs!
  warnings.warn(
/home2/harsha.vasamsetti/miniconda3/envs/slices/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymatgen/io/vasp/sets.py:118: BadInputSetWarning: POTCAR data with symbol Ni_pv is not known by pymatgen to correspond with the selected user_potcar_functional='PBE'. This POTCAR is known to correspond with functionals ['PBE_52', 'PBE_54']. Please verify that you are using the right POTCARs!
  warnings.warn(
/home2/harsha.vasamsetti/miniconda3/envs/slices/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymatgen/io/vasp/sets.py:118: BadInputSetWarning: POTCAR data with symbol P is not known by pymatgen to correspond with the selected user_potcar_functional='PBE'. This POTCAR is known to correspond with functionals ['PBE_52', 'PBE_54']. Please verify that you are using the right POTCARs!
  warnings.warn(
/home2/harsha.vasamsetti/miniconda3/envs/slices/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymatgen/io/vasp/sets.py:118: BadInputSetWarning: POTCAR data with symbol O is not known by pymatgen to correspond with the selected user_potcar_functional='PBE'. This POTCAR is known to correspond with functionals ['PBE_52', 'PBE_54']. Please verify that you are using the right POTCARs!
  warnings.warn(
ERROR:VaspErrorHandler:ZBRENT: fatal error in bracketing
/home2/harsha.vasamsetti/miniconda3/envs/slices/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymatgen/io/vasp/sets.py:118: BadInputSetWarning: POTCAR data with symbol P is not known by pymatgen to correspond with the selected user_potcar_functional='PBE'. This POTCAR is known to correspond with functionals ['PBE_52', 'PBE_54']. Please verify that you are using the right POTCARs!
  warnings.warn(
/home2/harsha.vasamsetti/miniconda3/envs/slices/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymatgen/io/vasp/sets.py:118: BadInputSetWarning: POTCAR data with symbol Os_pv is not known by pymatgen to correspond with the selected user_potcar_functional='PBE'. This POTCAR is known to correspond with functionals ['PBE_52', 'PBE_54']. Please verify that you are using the right POTCARs!
  warnings.warn(
/home2/harsha.vasamsetti/miniconda3/envs/slices/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymatgen/io/vasp/sets.py:118: BadInputSetWarning: POTCAR data with symbol O is not known by pymatgen to correspond with the selected user_potcar_functional='PBE'. This POTCAR is known to correspond with functionals ['PBE_52', 'PBE_54']. Please verify that you are using the right POTCARs!
  warnings.warn(
/home2/harsha.vasamsetti/miniconda3/envs/slices/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymatgen/io/vasp/outputs.py:303: UnconvergedVASPWarning: /scratch/harsha.vasamsetti_band/vasp_run_3/vasprun.xml is an unconverged VASP run.
Electronic convergence reached: True.
Ionic convergence reached: False.
  warnings.warn(msg, UnconvergedVASPWarning)
/home2/harsha.vasamsetti/miniconda3/envs/slices/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymatgen/io/vasp/sets.py:118: BadInputSetWarning: POTCAR data with symbol Cs_sv is not known by pymatgen to correspond with the selected user_potcar_functional='PBE'. This POTCAR is known to correspond with functionals ['PBE_52', 'PBE_54']. Please verify that you are using the right POTCARs!
  warnings.warn(
/home2/harsha.vasamsetti/miniconda3/envs/slices/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymatgen/io/vasp/sets.py:118: BadInputSetWarning: POTCAR data with symbol In_d is not known by pymatgen to correspond with the selected user_potcar_functional='PBE'. This POTCAR is known to correspond with functionals ['PBE_52', 'PBE_54']. Please verify that you are using the right POTCARs!
  warnings.warn(
/home2/harsha.vasamsetti/miniconda3/envs/slices/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymatgen/io/vasp/sets.py:118: BadInputSetWarning: POTCAR data with symbol Ga_d is not known by pymatgen to correspond with the selected user_potcar_functional='PBE'. This POTCAR is known to correspond with functionals ['PBE_52', 'PBE_54']. Please verify that you are using the right POTCARs!
  warnings.warn(
/home2/harsha.vasamsetti/miniconda3/envs/slices/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymatgen/io/vasp/sets.py:118: BadInputSetWarning: POTCAR data with symbol I is not known by pymatgen to correspond with the selected user_potcar_functional='PBE'. This POTCAR is known to correspond with functionals ['PBE_52', 'PBE_54']. Please verify that you are using the right POTCARs!
  warnings.warn(
/home2/harsha.vasamsetti/miniconda3/envs/slices/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymatgen/io/vasp/sets.py:118: BadInputSetWarning: POTCAR data with symbol Ba_sv is not known by pymatgen to correspond with the selected user_potcar_functional='PBE'. This POTCAR is known to correspond with functionals ['PBE_52', 'PBE_54']. Please verify that you are using the right POTCARs!
  warnings.warn(
/home2/harsha.vasamsetti/miniconda3/envs/slices/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymatgen/io/vasp/sets.py:118: BadInputSetWarning: POTCAR data with symbol Sr_sv is not known by pymatgen to correspond with the selected user_potcar_functional='PBE'. This POTCAR is known to correspond with functionals ['PBE_52', 'PBE_54']. Please verify that you are using the right POTCARs!
  warnings.warn(
/home2/harsha.vasamsetti/miniconda3/envs/slices/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymatgen/io/vasp/sets.py:118: BadInputSetWarning: POTCAR data with symbol Sb is not known by pymatgen to correspond with the selected user_potcar_functional='PBE'. This POTCAR is known to correspond with functionals ['PBE_52', 'PBE_54']. Please verify that you are using the right POTCARs!
  warnings.warn(
/home2/harsha.vasamsetti/miniconda3/envs/slices/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymatgen/io/vasp/sets.py:118: BadInputSetWarning: POTCAR data with symbol Br is not known by pymatgen to correspond with the selected user_potcar_functional='PBE'. This POTCAR is known to correspond with functionals ['PBE_52', 'PBE_54']. Please verify that you are using the right POTCARs!
  warnings.warn(
/home2/harsha.vasamsetti/miniconda3/envs/slices/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymatgen/io/vasp/sets.py:118: BadInputSetWarning: POTCAR data with symbol N is not known by pymatgen to correspond with the selected user_potcar_functional='PBE'. This POTCAR is known to correspond with functionals ['PBE_52', 'PBE_54']. Please verify that you are using the right POTCARs!
  warnings.warn(
/home2/harsha.vasamsetti/miniconda3/envs/slices/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymatgen/io/vasp/sets.py:118: BadInputSetWarning: POTCAR data with symbol Cl is not known by pymatgen to correspond with the selected user_potcar_functional='PBE'. This POTCAR is known to correspond with functionals ['PBE_52', 'PBE_54']. Please verify that you are using the right POTCARs!
  warnings.warn(
/home2/harsha.vasamsetti/miniconda3/envs/slices/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymatgen/io/vasp/sets.py:118: BadInputSetWarning: POTCAR data with symbol O is not known by pymatgen to correspond with the selected user_potcar_functional='PBE'. This POTCAR is known to correspond with functionals ['PBE_52', 'PBE_54']. Please verify that you are using the right POTCARs!
  warnings.warn(
/home2/harsha.vasamsetti/miniconda3/envs/slices/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymatgen/io/vasp/outputs.py:303: UnconvergedVASPWarning: /scratch/harsha.vasamsetti_band/vasp_run_5/vasprun.xml is an unconverged VASP run.
Electronic convergence reached: True.
Ionic convergence reached: False.
  warnings.warn(msg, UnconvergedVASPWarning)

